# Occasional deep pits on validation accuracy graph

Tags: keras

I'm training FER2013 data on a custom inceptionv3 architecture that have fewer layers and params (3.3M) than the vanilla one (25M). The graphs are looking like this:
[image]

What could be the possible explanation for this. I'm already using batchnorm and these pits doesn't makes much sense. Sequential models with fewer parameters than this one don't have this kind of behaviour.

P.S. Code added:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras import  Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (AveragePooling2D, concatenate,  
                                     Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, 
                                     BatchNormalization, Input, Activation,
                                     GlobalAveragePooling2D)
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint, CSVLogger


IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH = 128, 128
NB_EPOCH = 400
BATCH_SIZE = 256

model_name = "inceptionV3_module05"+"_imsize"+str(IMG_HEIGHT)+\
             "_bsize"+str(BATCH_SIZE)+"_epoch"+str(NB_EPOCH)  
csv_name = model_name + '_log.csv'
train_data_dir = "Training"
valid_data_dir = "PublicTest"
channel_axis=3
classes = 7


def conv2d_bn(x,
              filters,
              num_row,
              num_col,
              padding='same',
              strides=(1, 1),
              name=None):

    if name is not None:
        bn_name = name + '_bn'
        conv_name = name + '_conv'
    else:
        bn_name = None
        conv_name = None
    x = Conv2D(
        filters, (num_row, num_col),
        strides=strides,
        padding=padding,
        use_bias=False,
        name=conv_name)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=channel_axis, scale=False, name=bn_name)(x)
    x = Activation('relu', name=name)(x)
    return x

inputTensor = Input(shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1))

x = conv2d_bn(inputTensor, 32, 3, 3, strides=(2, 2))
x = conv2d_bn(x, 32, 3, 3)
x = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 3, 3)
x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)

x = conv2d_bn(x, 80, 1, 1)
x = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 3, 3)
x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)

# mixed 0: 35 x 35 x 256
branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)

branch3x3 = conv2d_bn(x, 48, 1, 1)
branch3x3 = conv2d_bn(branch3x3, 64, 3, 3)

branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)
branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)
branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)

branch_pool = AveragePooling2D((3, 3),
                                      strides=(1, 1),
                                      padding='same')(x)
branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 32, 1, 1)
x = concatenate(
    [branch1x1, branch3x3, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool],
    axis=channel_axis,
    name='mixed0')

# mixed 1: 35 x 35 x 288
branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)

branch3x3 = conv2d_bn(x, 48, 1, 1)
branch3x3 = conv2d_bn(branch3x3, 64, 3, 3)

branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)
branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)
branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)

branch_pool = AveragePooling2D((3, 3),
                                      strides=(1, 1),
                                      padding='same')(x)
branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 64, 1, 1)
x = concatenate(
    [branch1x1, branch3x3, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool],
    axis=channel_axis,
    name='mixed1')

    # mixed 2: 35 x 35 x 288
branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)

branch3x3 = conv2d_bn(x, 48, 1, 1)
branch3x3 = conv2d_bn(branch3x3, 64, 3, 3)

branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)
branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)
branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)

branch_pool = AveragePooling2D((3, 3),
                                      strides=(1, 1),
                                      padding='same')(x)
branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 64, 1, 1)
x = concatenate(
    [branch1x1, branch3x3, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool],
    axis=channel_axis,
    name='mixed2')

    # mixed 3: 17 x 17 x 768
branch3x3 = conv2d_bn(x, 384, 3, 3, strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')

branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 64, 1, 1)
branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3)
branch3x3dbl = conv2d_bn(
    branch3x3dbl, 96, 3, 3, strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')

branch_pool = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)
x = concatenate(
    [branch3x3, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool],
    axis=channel_axis,
    name='mixed3')

# mixed 4: 17 x 17 x 768
branch1x1 = conv2d_bn(x, 192, 1, 1)

branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(x, 128, 1, 1)
branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(branch7x7, 128, 1, 7)
branch7x7 = conv2d_bn(branch7x7, 192, 7, 1)

branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(x, 128, 1, 1)
branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 128, 7, 1)
branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 128, 1, 7)
branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 128, 7, 1)
branch7x7dbl = conv2d_bn(branch7x7dbl, 192, 1, 7)

branch_pool = AveragePooling2D((3, 3),
                                      strides=(1, 1),
                                      padding='same')(x)
branch_pool = conv2d_bn(branch_pool, 192, 1, 1)
x = concatenate(
    [branch1x1, branch7x7, branch7x7dbl, branch_pool],
    axis=channel_axis,
    name='mixed4')

x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(x)
x = Dense(classes, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

model = Model(inputTensor,x,name="incv3v1")



model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
#%%

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory = train_data_dir,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),    
    color_mode='grayscale',
    classes = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6'],
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle='False'

)
validation_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory = valid_data_dir,
    target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    classes = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6'],
    class_mode='categorical',    
    shuffle='False'
)

csv_logger = CSVLogger(csv_name , append=True, separator=';') 


callbacks_list=[csv_logger]

print("Starting to fit the model")



model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch = np.ceil(train_generator.samples/BATCH_SIZE),
                    validation_data = validation_generator,
                    validation_steps = np.ceil(validation_generator.samples/BATCH_SIZE),
                    epochs = NB_EPOCH, verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Comment: Can you share your loss and val_loss curves?
I will assume that your data set is not imbalanced as it is a standard one.

Comment: @EduardoDiSantiGrönros shared all the curves.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is that you are using stochastic gradient descent (SGD) and that is an unlucky mini-batch. That particular combination of training samples and model weights is not very good. There could be a disproportional number of outliers in that training batch.

Comment: I'm using adam as an optimizer. Attached code so you can further investigate it. Thanks. @BrianSpiering